# How to determine whether an asychronous call is the last one or not

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, asynchronous

Working with an asynchronous language (`node.js` in my case) I often end up with a two dimensional loop and an `response` at the very end:

```
firstArray.forEach(function(first){
     sencondArray[first].forEach(function(second){

         doStuff(function callback(resultSum){
             if(isLastCallback(this))
                 response.send(resultSum);
         });

     });
});
```

My first approach to get the proper result of `isLastCallback`, was using the provided counter `i` of both `forEach` iterations, but that ended up in a huge mess.

What is the common way to detect if the current run of `callback` is the last one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is to do several asynchronous calls and then combine the results.  You should look at the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module.  You probably want `async#parallel`.  It will run your async functions in parallel and then call the final callback with an array of all the results.